# Условие if в JAVA

Tags: java, spring

Как можно записать данное условие в Java, прилагаю примерный код в jquery

jquery

```
 else if($('#causezpzId').val()==24 && $('#rectif1zpzId').val()==0){
            $('.errorrep').append('<h3>Выберите Уточнение</h3>');
…
else if($('#causezpzId').val() == '24' && $('#rectif1zpzId').val() == '0') {
    … 
  if (i2==11 || i2==12) { $("#rectif2zpzId [value='" + i2 +"']").attr("selected", "selected")};  }
```

JAVA

```
  if(petit.getCausezpzId() == 24 && petit.getRectif1zpzId()==0){bindingResult.rejectValue("rectif1zpzId", "error.petit", "Выберите Уточнение");
 int i1 = petit.getRectif1zpzId();
 int i2 = petit.getRectif2zpzId();
if (i1==24 && i2==0) {КАК МОЖНО ЗАПИСАТЬ В  JAVA}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял симантику требуемого блока то тут все просто:

```
if (petit.getRectif2zpzId() == i2) { где то запомнить что данный элемент выбран }
```

Но честно говоря код зубодробильный...
вы сами доспустили ошибку при портации "i2==11 || i2==12" -> "i1==24 && i2==0"

И еще в Java сравнивать через == можно только примитивы...будте аккуратныю, если getRectif2zpzId и прочие методы позвращають не примитив, их надо сравнивать через equals

Comment: Дело в том что, когда срабатывает условие bindingResult.rejectValue("rectif1zpzId", "error.petit", "Выберите Уточнение" то уже заполненные поля сбрасываются и приходится выбирать заново. Вот я и привел аналог jquery if (i2==11 || i2==12) { $("#rectif2zpzId [value='" + i2 +"']").attr("selected", "selected")};  }

Comment: как это работало в JS на клиенте и какие задачи решало - понятно...но не свосем ясно что вы хотите получить от портирование в Java...Я лишь пытался опиреться на ваш код портации, и написать конструкцию вызвавшую у вас вопрос в семантической эквивалентонсти...в jquery семнатика была что если значение у элемента с Id rectif2zpzId равно i2, то измени его состояние в DOM. В Java же у вас нет состояния DOM, следовательно необходимо сделать подобие сохранения состояния в какой то вашей переменной которая будет подобием DOM на клиенте, чтобы после это наверное как то обработать...